# Flutter Image upload issue

Tags: php, image, api, flutter, image-uploading

I am trying to upload image using below function everything working fine only is i want to send image in post and when i am trying get image getting nothing

**This is for call API**

```
Future getUploadImg(access_token,File _image) async {
  print("Image: $_image");
  String apiUrl = '$_apiUrl/user/upload-profile-image';
  final length = await _image.length();
  final request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(apiUrl));
  request.headers['Accesstoken'] = "Bearer $access_token";
  request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile('imagefile',_image.openRead(), length));

  http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

**My file that is passing to server is:**

```
File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dotsquares.ecomhybrid/files/Pictures/c5df03f7-097d-47ca-a3c5-f896b2a38c086982492957343724084.jpg'
```

Comment: can you explain what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: when i am passing image with API params there isn't getting in POST or File method.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result finally we need to pass string for image sharing my working code if anyone need for help:

```
Future getUploadImg(access_token,File _image) async {
  print("Image: $_image");
  var result;
  var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(_image.openRead()));
  var length = await _image.length();
  var uri = Uri.parse('$_apiUrl/user/upload-profile-image');
  var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  request.headers['Accesstoken'] = "Bearer $access_token";
  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('imagefile', stream, length, filename: basename(_image.path));
  request.files.add(multipartFile);
  var response = await request.send();

  print(" ===================response code ${response.statusCode}");
  await response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(" =====================response value $value");
    result = value;
  });
  return json.decode(result);

}
```

Comment: I used the same above code, unfortunately i am getting below error
any clue? Thanks!

{"error":{"name":"MulterError","message":"Unexpected field","code":"LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE","field":"property","storageErrors":[]}}

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the following problems:

- write failed
- connection closed before ...
- Flutter Doctor Error - SocketException: Write failed (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32)

you need to add the correct parameters in the headers.

In my case, these problems occur with uploading images and sending base64 encoded requests. I solved it by adding the following 'connection' header: 'keep-alive':

```
  final response = await this.httpClient.put(
    url,
    encoding: Utf8Codec(),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': "*/*",
      'connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    },
    body: body,
  );
```